# how to show blog post hour in addition to the date in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show post hour posted in addition to post date in WordPress 
I tried to look in `template-tags.php` I couldn't discover how to do that?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_time

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `the_date` function

```
the_date("H:i " . get_option( 'date_format' ))
```